# Colorbox doesnt look properly after reloading page with javascript

Tags: colorbox

I am using colorbox in my project to show application forms and if the user closes colorbox page the main window will be refreshed with this script:

```
$(".form").colorbox({
        iframe: true,
        innerWidth: 755,
        innerHeight: 440,
        overlayClose: false,
        //main page refresh
        onClosed: function () {
            location.reload(true);
        }
```

but after page refresh if the user clicks on colorbox link the screen looks like this.

[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

i have found the problem, and i write the solution for the developers who has the same problem like me;

in index page i call javascript first, than css. it was the problem. i call first css and after that javascripts the problem solved